# what is the exact function of Server.TransferRequest()

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.Net MVC I wanted to redirect a user to an action like logoff but for security seasons that was crucial to that action happen but with `RedirectToAction()` method as i know it just made a 302 redirect message so it is up to client side to call that action I googled then find `Server.TransferRequest()` but there is no complete documentation use this method would you please provide me some link to any information about that method?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I saw that but it was not usefull!

Comment: So what is your real question? What is unclear to you?

Comment: would you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229893/prevent-users-without-confirmed-email-from-logging-in-asp-net-mvc-with-identity this is my problem

Comment: Answered you actual question.